# Entity Framework Support Default constrains from DataBase First approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have used Entity Framework 6.1.3 [DBContext] Database first approach in MVC application. I have a table with default constrains in a column[ex: default value 20].

When adding new record via stored procedure without the mentioned value of default constrain column, it's working fine[ new entry added into table with default value colum=20].

But when I try to add records via entity framework, it throws exception due to default constrain not being defined in EDMX [the default column value initialized as null, it's not manually defined in object before being added to context].

Can you suggest default constrain will support it in entity framework 6.0? And can you provide a solution to add default constrain value to table when you add record via EDMX?

Comment: You could create a partial class and then set the value in the constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691854/setting-default-value-in-entity-framework-database-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately default value constraints are not supported by Entity Framework 6.0.  They're  [reportedly](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first) coming in Entity Framework 7, though, and [Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/releases) is available now.